# Entity framework core One to One

Tags: entity-framework, ef-core-2.0

[The databse](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1PkP3.png)

(Project,Contest,LocalJob)-> Each one of them has 1 WorkDetails and 1 WorkDetails has one of them

Hello this is my database and I would like to ask you the following question:

Should I add a foreign key column in WorkDetails for project,contest or LocalJobs.

And if I have to how to implement navigational property?

Comment: Are you trying to map *existing* database? Because the relationships and FKs in question are different there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In code-first you could use owned types for this:

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using System.Linq;
using System;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace efCoreTest
{

    class Project
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public WorkDetail WorkDetail { get; set; }

    }
    class Contest
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public WorkDetail WorkDetail { get; set; }
    }
    class LocalJob
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public WorkDetail WorkDetail { get; set; }
    }
    class WorkDetail
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
        public DateTime EndDate { get; set; }
    }
    class Db : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<Project> Projects { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Contest> Contests { get; set; }
        public DbSet<LocalJob> LocalJobs { get; set; }

        protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
        {
            optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer("Server=.;Database=efCoreTest;Integrated Security=true");
        }
        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Entity<Project>().OwnsOne(p => p.WorkDetail);
            modelBuilder.Entity<Contest>().OwnsOne(p => p.WorkDetail);
            modelBuilder.Entity<LocalJob>().OwnsOne(p => p.WorkDetail);



            base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
        }
    }
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            using (var db = new Db())
            {
                db.Database.EnsureDeleted();
                db.Database.EnsureCreated();


            }

        }
    }
}
```